# phalcon volt "javascript_include" how to add async or defer in the include URL

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, phalcon, volt

when i use this line of code in .volt

```
{{ javascript_include('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBizbimR5WObPb2Euy4ICC-dZp8Mm7Y7cM&callback=initMap') }}
```

in view source of the browser it shows like this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBizbimR5WObPb2Euy4ICC-dZp8Mm7Y7cM&callback=initMap"></script>
```

and my map doesn't work it requires "defer" in include url like below output

how i can achieve below using  `javascript_include`

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBizbimR5WObPb2Euy4ICC-dZp8Mm7Y7cM&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
{{ javascript_include( [ "src":"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBizbimR5WObPb2Euy4ICC-dZp8Mm7Y7cM&callback=initMap" , "async":"true", "defer":"true" ] ) }}
```

Rendered this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBizbimR5WObPb2Euy4ICC-dZp8Mm7Y7cM&amp;callback=initMap" async="true" defer="true"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the AssetManager, but i'm not sure about from volt.

Edit: it looks like maybe? i'm not super familiar with phalcon, look [here](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1206/add-assets-in-volt)

Take a look at this:
Check the documentation here:

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Assets_Manager.html

```
$this->asset->addJs('path/to/file', null, false, array('async' => 'async', 'defer' => 'defer'));
```

Comment: i am using volt template is that possible in that? because i noticed it is for twig

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to answer Naeem's question about volt template and asserts management.

Here is a link to assets management for Phalcon:
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/assets.html

Note volt syntax in the view:

```
{{ assets.outputJs() }}
```

In the controller:

```
$this->assets->addJs('path/to/file', null, false, array('async' => 'async', 'defer' => 'defer'));
```

Comment: $this->asset part is giving me error do you know how i will include assets in controller?

Comment: I believe my answer answered Dec 2 at 18:56 is the correct answer and directly deals with your original issue. Did you try that? As to your euro yu haven't posted the error. Also I believe there is a typo in this answer. $this->asset->addJs(... should be $this->assets->addJs(...